# how to get the selected date in calendar card library?

Tags: android, date, calendar

I have an android application that display a calendar card to pick a date

I used this library [android-calendarview](https://github.com/SimonVT/android-calendarview)

and it's work fine !! but how can I get the selected date ?!

any help please !?

thanks in advance :)

my layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <net.simonvt.calendarview.CalendarView
        android:layout_width="245dip"
        android:layout_height="280dip" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_change_date"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_white_with_border"
            android:text="Change"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_cancel_date"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_white_with_border"
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you post your java code

Comment: my java code just casting these element , you have to check the library >>>> everything does here : https://github.com/SimonVT/android-calendarview/blob/master/library/src/net/simonvt/calendarview/CalendarView.java

Comment: you can add `setOnDateChangeListener()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add `setOnDateChangeListener()` to your `CalanderView` object and the get method call back when ever there is a Date changed event.

Comment: man , do you know how to set the default value that set before do any select ?!

Comment: the link you posted has this method `public void setDate(long date) { setDate(date, false, false);  }` so try `setDate(long date)`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to call this method ?

```
public Calendar getSelectedDay() {
            return mSelectedDate;
        }
```

[Calendar View line 1391 to 1393](https://github.com/SimonVT/android-calendarview/blob/master/library/src/net/simonvt/calendarview/CalendarView.java)

Comment: thank you man , I figured out that I can get the selected date by using > setOnDateChangeListener()

maybe your method will work fine too :)